# Change date to 24 hours format in JS

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have the following date variable : `const datum = new Date("2022-09-04T22:07:56+02:00")`
Which gives me the date :  `"2022-09-04T22:07:56+02:00"`.
I now want to format this date to look like the following : `"04.9.2022 22:07:56"`.

I was trying to use Moment.js which worked only partly :

```
datum =  moment(datum, 'YYYY-M-DD hh:mm:ss').format('DD.M.YYYY hh:mm:ss')
```

Which gives me the following : `"04.9.2022 10:07:56"` this would be correct if we would use the 12 hour clock, but we are using the 24 hour clock, so I need this instead : `"04.9.2022 22:07:56"`

Is there a way to change that the way I need it to be ?

Comment: I havent used moment, but usually HH is 24 hour clock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing 'hh' to 'HH'.

```
moment(new Date("2022-09-04T22:07:56+02:00"),'YYYY-M-DD HH:mm:ss').format("DD.M.YYYY HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try my code:

```js
const now = new Date("2022-09-04T22:07:56+02:00");
let options = {
        month:"2-digit",
            day:"2-digit",
            hourCycle: 'h23',
            hour: "2-digit",
            minute: "numeric",
            second: "numeric",
            year:"numeric"
        }
let result=now.toLocaleTimeString("en-GB", options);
result=result.replaceAll("/",".");
result=result.replace(",","");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can pass the offset value to retain the input offset value

```js
let datum = new Date("2022-09-04T22:07:56+02:00");

let offset = moment.parseZone("2022-09-04T22:07:56+02:00").utcOffset();

let finalDate = moment(datum).utcOffset(offset).format("DD.M.YYYY HH:mm:ss");
console.log(finalDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `hh` to `HH`:

```js
moment(new Date("2022-09-04T22:07:56+02:00"), 'YYYY-M-DD HH:mm:ss').format("DD.M.YYYY HH:mm:ss");
```